# Find IP address of remote server

Tags: c#, c++

I have dll that using in one my application. This dll connect to one remote server and post and get some data.
When I run this dll in my application, How I can find IP address of this remote server?
Dll written by C++.
Possible find that?
I am using Win7.
Regards,

Comment: How do you connect to the remote server if you don't know the address to it?

Comment: I used another dll that another guy made that.

Comment: I'd launch Wireshark and check the network traffic.

Comment: You mean the IP address is hard-coded in the dll?

Comment: Wireshark is free tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the endpoints with netstat: `netstat -an -p tcp`

It comes with Windows.

Comment: This shows list of all IPs. How I can find specific IP?

Comment: `netstat -ano` includes PID, look for your own PID.

Comment: Thanks. My dll using by another software. I must check PID for my exe file?

Comment: You can also use netstat -b in combination with the other options in order to see the name of the executable that uses the connection. In that case you need to open the command line as administrator.